# What species of tree is this?

Tags: species-identification, trees

We have this cute little tree in our front yard (Denver CO):
[image]
[image]

Unfortunately we have to get our water main replaced and this tree lies right in the path of destruction. Anybody know what species it is? And, in your opinion, is it worth saving?

Comment: Please add your location (country, state) and if possible where the tree comes from (wild or planted), that will make it much easier to id.

Comment: I am in Denver CO. The tree is planted. Its a residential area.

Comment: Looks vaguely [apple-ish](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=apple+tree+leaves) to me, but with a cultivated tree, it may be hard to tell (especially as other fruit trees also look similar). Take a look at the base of the trunk - is there any indication that the top portion has been grafted onto a different rootstock? If so, it's a strong indication it's a fruit tree, though without some sort of tag, telling which variety it is may be difficult/impossible.